# Java: Using JVM argument -XX:ErrorFile and append the logs in existing log file without pid

Tags: java, logging, crash-dumps, jvm-crash

I have following configuration for my service

> exec java -Djava.io.tmpdir=$tmpdir -Djava.library.path="Some_Path"
>   -Xmx"$heapsize"m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="Do something, may be restart"
>   -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/service/myService/"myServiceCrash".log -jar .jar

I am not able to append the crash logs into the same file. But new file with new PID is created every time.

Requirement : Dump crash logs into same file.

Comment: What is the JDK version you are trying on?

Comment: I am using openjdk version "1.8.0_151"

Comment: Ok great, i will have a look,

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. For the first time it will write to the file provided in -XX:ErrorFile=, Once the file exists it won't be overwritten and you will then get the default error file.

Ideally there should be some way top show the file creation fails, but it can't be done as part of the error handling code.
Please check the evaluation here - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189672

Comment: Exactly, it is not customizable. I created my own bash to maintain the single log for the time being. Anyways, thanks... cheers